# Iterate n-levels of linked lists Java

Tags: java, linked-list, tree, nodes

I have a tree with nodes, and each node contains a list with nodes, and each node in those lists contain nodes... It can be 10 levels deep, with around 100 node objects.

I've tried to iterate to find all individual node objects but most guides covers binary trees.. It's just overwhelming. If anyone has some pseudo code or can point me in the right direction I would be very glad. Classes below (sorry about the bad formatting):

**Node**

```
public class Node {
    public String text;
    public LinkedList<Node> nodes;

    public Node() {
        this.nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

    public Node(String data) {
        this();
        this.text = data;
    }
}
```

**Tree**

```
public class Tree {
    public LinkedList<Node> nodes;
    public String text;

    public Tree() {
        nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

    public Tree(String data) {
        this();
        this.text = data;
    }
}
```

**Program**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Tree> trees = new LinkedList<Tree>();

        trees.add(new Tree("Root 1"));

        trees.get(0).nodes.add(new Node("Node 1"));
        trees.get(0).nodes.add(new Node("Node 2"));
        trees.get(0).nodes.add(new Node("Node 3"));

        trees.get(0).nodes.get(0).nodes.add(new Node("Node 1:Child 1"));
        trees.get(0).nodes.get(1).nodes.add(new Node("Node 2:Child 1"));
        trees.get(0).nodes.get(2).nodes.add(new Node("Node 3:Child 1"));

        for (Tree tree : trees) {
            tree.nodes.. // find all node-objects
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by recursion. Since you have maximum depth of 10 and max elements = 100, recursion should not give any performance issues. Sample code to do this:

```
List<Node> flattenTree(List<Node> nodes){
    List<Node> allNodes=new LinkedList<>(nodes) ;
    for(Node node:nodes){
        {
           if(node.getNodes()!=null)
           allNodes.addAll(flattenTree(node.getNodes()));
        } 
     return allNodes;
    }
```

Call this using:

```
List<Node> allNodes = flattenTree(tree.getNodes);
```

allNodes will contain all the nodes of this tree.

Comment: Tried this but, got ConcurrentModificationException... must have done something wrong, but I like your idea of a flat tree :)

Comment: Sry, your are right. Edited the code. It will work now.

Comment: This worked for me. I tried recursion myself before but always ended up in a never ending loop, but this code was flawless

Comment: Glad to know that... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using recursion:

```
interface TreeOp {
    void apply(Tree tree);
}
```

...

```
void traverse(Tree tree, TreeOp op) {
    op.apply(tree);
    for (Tree child: tree.nodes) {
        traverse(child, op);
    }
}
```

...

```
for (Tree tree : trees) {
    traverse(tree, (tree) -> {
       doSomethingWith(tree);
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

Actually, you can use the Consumer interface instead of defining a new one:

```
void traverse(Tree tree, Consumer<Tree> op) {
    op.accept(tree);
    for (Tree child: tree.nodes) {
        traverse(child, op);
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

And traverse could be a method of Tree:

```
void traverse(Consumer<Tree> op) {
    op.accept(this);
    for (Tree child: nodes) {
        traverse(child, op);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never used a Consumer before, but I will try your solution out as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, what kind of problem would require a data structure like this?

Something like this in `main` should set you on the right track:

```
// set up the master list of all nodes and the list of unvisited nodes
// with the base tree's node.
List<Node> allTheNodes = new LinkedList<>();
allTheNodes.add(tree.node);
List<Node> unvisited = new LinkedList<>();
unvisited.add(tree.node);

while (!unvisited.isEmpty())
{
    // while our unvisited list is not empty, visit the first node in the list
    // and add all of its subnodes to both the list of nodes to visit and the master list of nodes.
    Node currentNode = unvisited.get(0);
    allTheNodes.addAll(currentNode.nodes);
    unvisited.addAll(currentNode.nodes);
    unvisited.remove(currentNode);
}   

// now, allTheNodes should have all of your nodes in it.
```

Comment: Hm, maybe it's not the best structure. But I have product category, and in each category I have sub categories of tools which can contain related tools, and lastly spare parts..

Comment: Oh I see. You should consider making this easier to conceptualize by  making a class for each type or level of your catalog and then adding member variables to each class to represent the hierarchy. You'd effectively turn a nested list problem into something much more readable by doing this.

Comment: @Abdil Yes but tools can have up to 5 sub levels. So it's Category->Tools->tools sub1->tools sub2.. and so on. That is my main problem at the moment. Then spare parts can be added to each sub level, and also contain sub levels such as spare parts pack -> spare part

Comment: That's a gnarly problem. Maybe a tree structure could work. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to track the depth of the nodes:

```
LinkedList<Node> currentNodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
currentNodes.add(root);
int depth = 0;
while depth < 10 {
    depth++;
    int size = currentNodes.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Node current = currentNodes.removeFirst();
        //Do something with current
        for (int j = 0; j < current.nodes.size(); j++) {
            currentNodes.addLast(current.nodes.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```